Problems with stopping JavaScript animation with multiple queues

  See the Pen 
  animate queue problem by 양갱 (@abllmjdn-the-builder)
  on CodePen.

$(".start").click(function(){
    $(".anime1").animate({
        left:'50%',
    },2000);
    $(".anime1").animate({
        left:0,
    },1000);
})


$(".stop").click(function(){
    $(".anime1").clearQueue().stop()
})

As above, I composed an animation with two queues.
During the first queue, press the stop button and press the restart button to stop and start well.
However, if you press the stop button on the second queue and then the start button, the second queue will not be executed, but the first queue will be executed.
Is there any way to solve this?

Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor HERE at SO

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
